# setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor) not working if called just after a message box

Tags: c++, qt

```
QMessageBox::information(this, "hello", "hello");
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
QThread::sleep(5);
QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
```

When above code is executed, I expect wait cursor to be set during 5 seconds. But wait cursor doesn't appear at all. If I remove the message box in the beginning, wait cursor comes and stays for 5 seconds as expected.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static message box methods use `exec()`, so it stops executing of your current code. Sleep from `QThread` blocks whole main thread, it means no updates, no repainting, just freezing GUI.

Solution:

Don't use static message box methods, create new box on heap and set special flag to avoid memory leaks:

```
QMessageBox *box = new QMessageBox;
box->setText(...);
//add info to box
box->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
box->exec();
```

Don't use `QThread::sleep`, use `singleshot` from `QTimer`, just create some slot where you restore cursor:

```
//override cursor
QTimer::singleShot(time,this,SLOT(slotWhichRestoresCursor()));
```

And in this case all your operations will be asynchronous and GUI will not be freezed.

Comment: QMessageBox::show() doesn't block. I need my message box to block until user responds to it.

Comment: @LahiruChandima sleep() in main thread is wrong and bad, use singleShot, secondly, do you want modal message box? Then set box->setModal(true); (static method calls exec() but exec() calls modal dialog by default, so you need create modal box too)

Comment: Actually I do not use a sleep in my actual code. I am doing some CPU intensive work. But the effect is the same as a sleep isn't it? By the way, I used box->exec() instead of box->show() and now the wait cursor appears. Any explanation?

Comment: @LahiruChandima firstly, yes, I just don't know that it is just example. Secondly, exec should block executing and when you close your window it starts to execute code with overriding cursor. Is problem solved?

Comment: Thanks Chernobyl. My problem is now solved but I didn't clearly understand how it got solved because as you have told, static method QMessageBox::information() too internally uses exec(), just as non static exec().

Comment: Yes it calls exec too but with object created in stack. To prove see actual source code: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/157da36977213237939df14608753bb3ec280f0b:src/gui/dialogs/qmessagebox.cpp#L1926 I used pointers, but to be honest stack faster than heap, so you can try also change my code:try to use simple stack(not pointers), maybe it will work too.  Maybe problem also in: when your program does not respond(long calculations or sleep) then OS Windows set wait cursor automatically.